# why cant we use orginal for loop for Set

Tags: java, list, set

The basic difference between the set and the list is that set wont allow the duplicates 
the question is why cant we use original for loop for the set as we use for list

eg: length of set and list is same

```
   for(int i =0 ; i< list.size;i++){
    list.get(i);
    set.get(i);  // here it is throwing an error like get(index ) cant be applied for set
```

}

but if i use advance for loop(for each) its working

```
for(Object sample : set){
 system.out.println(sample);
```

}

why is this happening ... is there any operational defference between for loop and for each , set and list ....

any help and suggestion would be  useful ... thank you in advance

Comment: A set has no `get()` method. You should check the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Answer (score 6):

A `Set` doesn't have an order, and therefore it doesn't have a `get(index)` method. Therefore you can't call `set.get(i)`.

The enhanced for loop, on the other hand, works with any class that implements `Iterable` (as well as with arrays), which includes any `Collection`. For `Set`s it will iterate over the elements in an order that depends on the specific `Set` implementation.

Comment: You can get a Set iterator which would allow you to use a iterator for loop, using <set>.iterator()

Comment: thank you :) @Eran and i am using set.iterator().next().toString() to get the elements